# Function output changes after one use

Tags: c++, function

I asked this 2 days ago, but I didn`t give enough information to solve the bug, this time I will be more specific and I will provide the full code. Now I've been debugging for a while and I realised something new:

I have this function:

```
double calc_value(string equation, int degree, char _for)
{
 string monom[100];
 Monomial monomial[100];
 double val_sum[100];

 memset(val_sum,0,sizeof(val_sum));

 for(int i = 0; i < count_monom(equation); i++)
 {
  monom[i] = obt_mon_from(equation,i);
  monomial[i] = str_to_monomial(equation,i,monom[i],_for);

  if(monomial[i].member == 2)
  monomial[i].value *= -1;

  val_sum[monomial[i].degree] += monomial[i].value;
 }

 return val_sum[degree];
}
```

And when called like this: `calc_value("8x^9 - 2x = 3 - 2x^5 + 2x^8 + 1.5x^3",9,'x')` the output must be 8, as it calculates the value of the monomial of 9th degree. It works when I use it one time, but after the first use it starts outputting -8.

This is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string eq = "8x^9 - 2x = 3 - 2x^5 + 2x^8 + 1.5x^3";

    cout << calc_value(eq,9,'x') << " ";
    cout << calc_value(eq,9,'x') << " ";
    cout << calc_value(eq,9,'x');

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

The output, as I said, is "8 -8 -8" when it should be "8 8 8".

Here is the full "algebra" header (the other 2 are not important): pastebin.com/wcy94zXN

By the way: I checked every array in the important functions and they dont overflow and the program works fine in debug mode (Code::Blocks, GCC compiler).

Comment: Isn't this just the same as [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087792/strange-bug-that-is-solved-with-a-cout) ?

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with this: `if(monomial[i].member == 2) monomial[i].value *= -1;`, which in turn is the result of `str_to_monomial`

Comment: Regardless of whether arrays overflow or not for your specific case, it is extremely bad practice to use fixed-length arrays without bounds-checking. This can lead to security vulnerabilities of catastrophic proportions. Consider either doing some serious bounds checking, or using something like a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Do any of the functions you call inside your function have any static data members?  Have you stepped through the code an watch what happens?  Stepping through your code is one of the best ways to find where things are going awry.

Comment: `double val_sum[100] = {};` is sufficient to create an array of 0.0s.

Comment: jschultz410, I checked `str_to_monomial` output and it works as it should and `monomial[i].member` is right too. NathanOliver, I cannot check the code in that function because when I use `cout << monomial[i].value << endl` the bug magically disappears. Paul R, it is basically the same question with more information and a link to the full code.

Comment: Monomial ? How is that type defined? The provided code can't be the root cause so I guess it is something inside Monomial

Comment: Unless you provide some code that people can compile and run I don't think you're going to get any help here.

Comment: Jonathan Potter, you are right, here you have the full project: http://www.mediafire.com/download/ukd2nb7izqn2i8v/algebra.rar

Comment: Your definition of "full code" is clearly nowhere near the same as mine. It's like saying "I'll give my full address: 28" - unless you have the rest of my address, that's about as useful as a chocolate teapot - even if you know what town or village I live in, it's not particularly useful, as there may be more than one street where the number 28 is a possible place to live. [Note for paranoid: No, I don't live on 28 anything, it's just an example].

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't give the full code. I just posted a download link for the full project.